# How can I configure doctrine with migrations?

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework3, laminas

I have this problem when I try to generate a migration from the terminal. How can I configure doctrine with migration?

https://i.ibb.co/HqWYBdT/imagen.png

Answer (score 0):

```
'doctrine' => [
    'migrations_configuration' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'table_storage' => [
                'table_name' => 'migrations',
                'version_column_name' => 'version',
                'version_column_length' => 1024,
                'executed_at_column_name' => 'executedAt',
                'execution_time_column_name' => 'executionTime',
            ],
            'migrations_paths' => [
                'Migrations' => 'data/Migrations',
            ], // an array of namespace => path
            'migrations' => [], // an array of fully qualified migrations
            'all_or_nothing' => false,
            'check_database_platform' => true,
            'organize_migrations' => 'none', // year or year_and_month
            'custom_template' => null,
        ],
    ],
],
```